# NSImage from byte array

Tags: cocoa, monomac

I'm trying to display an image in a NSImageView, with an image contained in a Byte array. How can I do this? From what I understand I need to convert my byte[] to an NSData variable and feed that to an NSImage. Is this correct? How do I do it? I've tried casting and that doesn't work, and there doesn't seem to be any conversion built in...

I have tried the following:

Casting:

```
NSData bytesAsMacVariable = (NSData) imageAsBytes;
```

Also tried

```
NSData bytesAsMacVariable = imageAsBytes as NSData;
```

Finally, tried to pass a byte[] as if it was a NSData.

```
NSImage imageToShow = new NSImage(imageAsBytes);
```

None of these will work, and as far as I can see, neither NSImage or NSData has a member function that accepts byte[] for conversion...

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the code you’ve tried. In general, what you’ve described is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're casting to the object type, but you should cast to *pointer-to-object* type.
Try something more like

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithBytes:byteArray length:arrayLength];
NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
[imageView setImage:image];
[image release];
```

The pointers are very important.

Comment: @Robin also note that, if the byte array is guaranteed not to go away, you can optimize the NSData by using one of the `NSData` `...WithBytesNoCopy:` methods. -- and here it's probably ok even if the `byteArray` will not persist, since the `NSImage` presumably copies the data out of the `NSData` anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an NSMutableData, like this:

```
new NSImage (new NSMutableData (imageAsBytes));
```

Comment: Conceptually, that's the same thing I posted, but what language are you using where that is valid and meaningful syntax?

Comment: The question was tagged monomac and cocoa, which is the mono binding for cocoa/mac development.  The source syntax is C#.

Comment: will the `new NSMutableData(imageAsBytes)` copy the bytes or use them in-place?