# Converting UIImage to Byte Array

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I need to convert a UIImage to a byte array.  I am using Xamarin's Visual Studio plugin to produce an iOS application.

The bit of code below gets the image, but I need to send it across a Service Stack as a byte array instead of a UIImage.

```
        var signatureView = new SignaturePad.SignaturePadView(new RectangleF(10, 660, 300, 150));
        signatureView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
        this.View.AddSubview(signatureView);
        UIImage signatureImage = signatureView.GetImage();
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Shamelessly stolen from [ChrisNTR](http://weblogs.asp.net/chrishardy/archive/2009/11/03/converting-a-uiimage-to-a-bytearray-in-monotouch.aspx)

```
using (NSData imageData = image.AsPNG()) {
  Byte[] myByteArray = new Byte[imageData.Length];
  System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(imageData.Bytes, myByteArray, 0, Convert.ToInt32(imageData.Length));
}
```

Answer (score 17):

It's been a long time since I checked the ServiceStack API but, **if possible**, try to avoid `byte[]` since it will need to create another copy of the same data. It does not matter in many cases but images are often huge.

E.g. if there's an overload that accept a `System.IO.Stream` then use `image.AsPNG ().AsStream ()` and avoid the overhead :-)

Comment: Using image.AsPNG() does not keep the orientation flag, so it seems better to use image.AsJPEG() to get the stream. That took me two hours ;-).

Answer (score 14):

```
Stream pst =   img.AsPNG().AsStream();
```

Comment: You could also use .ToArray();