# Convert 'Xamarin.Form.Image' type 'byte[]'

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am supposed to get an Image from a url and convert it into `byte[]`. The following is what I achieved

```
var webImage = new Image { Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit };
webImage.Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new    Uri("http://xamarin.com/content/images/pages/forms/example-app.png"));
```

but now I am unable to convert the Image type to `byte[]`.

Is this the correct way to approach? Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting UIImage to Byte Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112314/converting-uiimage-to-byte-array)

Comment: Its not a duplicate, the question you pointed out as duplicate is iOS only

Comment: @Rohit Correct, but you will have to do it on a per platform basis.

Comment: So then a good way should be creating an interface in the forms project and implementing it in each platform.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but from my initial thought you will need a Stream. 
For that you could use `StreamImageSource`

From there you can use the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27532462/is-there-a-cross-platform-solution-to-imagesource-to-byte).

Comment: public static byte[] ReadStreamIntoByte (Stream input)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                input.CopyTo(ms);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }

does not work with StreamImageSource as input parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Forms inside it uses `IImageSourceHandler` which has realizations like

- `ImageLoaderSourceHandler` - for UriImageSource
- `StreamImagesourceHandler` - for StreamImageSource
- and so on

For reading data from `UriImageSource` You should use `ImageLoaderSourceHandler` which is platform class. So under each platform use code like

```
var handler = new ImageLoaderSourceHandler();
var uiimage = await handler.LoadImageAsync(source, new CancellationToken(), UIScreen.MainScreenScale);
```

Then you can reach any data from UIImage under iOS or from Bitmap under Android. There are a lot of tutorials how to get byte[] from them.

Answer (score 0):

FFImageLoading (https://github.com/molinch/FFImageLoading/) `CachedImage` has `GetImageAsJPG` and `GetImageAsPNG` methods. It's a direct Xamarin.Forms `Image` class replacement with a lot of additional features.

Here's the code used for image retrieving (it can be used in a `Image` class custom renderers):

- [Android](https://github.com/molinch/FFImageLoading/blob/028f3469fbee0707c86bd13bcdc76b1e608a9c7c/source/FFImageLoading.Forms.Droid/CachedImageRenderer.cs#L288-L332)
- [iOS](https://github.com/molinch/FFImageLoading/blob/028f3469fbee0707c86bd13bcdc76b1e608a9c7c/source/FFImageLoading.Forms.Touch/CachedImageRenderer.cs#L300-L326)
- [Windows](https://github.com/molinch/FFImageLoading/blob/028f3469fbee0707c86bd13bcdc76b1e608a9c7c/source/FFImageLoading.Forms.WinRT/CachedImageRenderer.cs#L320-L403)

Comment: Is your provided solution a solution to the question? 

I also wonder if it is still in development, because I cant build the solution.  "FFImageLoading.Transformations.Windows" is not compatible with uap10.0" or "wpa81" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It's posible to use WebClient to obtain byte array from a URL.

```
var webClient = new WebClient ();
byte[] byteImage = webClient.DownloadData (imageURL);
```