# how can I get the pixel data from a Xamarin.IOS UIImage?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, uiimage

How can I get the pixel data bytes from a Xamarin.IOS UIImage object or from a Xamarin.IOS UIImageView.Image ?

I want to get the pixel data bytes so I can write them to a file, and later use LoadFromData() to load the UIImage.

Comment: LoadFromData expects data in a supported image format (png, jpg, etc) not raw pixel data.  Based on what you've posted before I think the best approach would be to save the image as a jpg on the windows side, before you stream it to iOS

Comment: Agreed, thanks.  On the Windows side, I'm using UWP and so now I know how Alice in Wonderland felt.   ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
    using (NSData imageData = image.AsPNG()) {
  Byte[] myByteArray = new Byte[imageData.Length];
  System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(imageData.Bytes, myByteArray, 0, Convert.ToInt32(imageData.Length));
}
```

Source: [Converting UIImage to Byte Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112314/converting-uiimage-to-byte-array)