# Issues with screen capture on OS X - CGDisplayCreateImage

Tags: c, xcode, macos, screenshot, quartz-graphics

I am using `CGDisplayCreateImage(CGMainDisplayID())` to capture screen. When we do a fast user switch to another user, it still captures screen from first user. `CGMainDisplayID()` on second user returns 1104977152. Any idea why this is happening?

My intention is to capture active screen. In case of mirroring, I don't mind capturing the active display.

Other than Quartz APIs, any other suggestions?

Comment: My first guess is that your app is running under the first user's uid.  You probably need to run your app as "`root`" or "`admin`" (perhaps as a helper tool?) and then you also probably need to detect which user is in the foreground and active.  What exactly are trying to accomplish here?

Comment: app is running as root. I can detect which user is active and foreground, but how does that help?